# Meta tag para geolocalização

Tags: html, geolocalização, html-meta-tag

Estava procurando se existem meta tags para geolocalização, para ajudarem os motores de busca saber que as informações do meu site se referem a uma cidade específica.

Achei esse [site](http://www.geo-tag.de/generator/en.html) que gera as seguintes tags para um endereço que digitei:

```
<meta name="geo.region" content="US-VA" />
<meta name="geo.placename" content="Fairfax" />
<meta name="geo.position" content="38.844573;-77.286766" />
<meta name="ICBM" content="38.844573, -77.286766" />
```

Procurei no [www.w3.org](http://www.w3.org) e no [www.w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/) algo relacionado a essas tags e não achei.

Essas tags `geo.` existem efetivamente? Estão em desenvolvimento? Os motores de busca interpretam elas?

Comment: http://searchengineland.com/should-you-geotag-pages-for-local-seo-22531

Answer (score 5):

Vou responder até onde eu sei sobre sua pergunta, haha
O Google que detém 45% das pesquisas da internet, não reconhece esse meta tag. 
As que ele reconhece estão aqui: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=pt-BR
Já vi gente usando estas tags(apesar de não saber muito sobre) e se, elas realmente forem úteis para o seu projeto, use-as!

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente com base nas respostas dadas e links providos, essas metatags não consideradas por todos os motores, principalmente pelo Google, conforme resposta do Giancarlo Soldera Graziano, e há pouco material disponível sobre isso.

O motivo para qual eu queria essas tags está na pergunta original:

> ....para ajudarem os motores de busca saber que as informações do meu site se referem a uma cidade específica.

Tentando achar a resposta, me deparei com outro conceito: *dados estruturados*. Sei que não perguntei sobre isso, mas é porque eu não sabia que isso existia, e na verdade era bem isso que eu estava procurando, mas não sabia.

Usando dados estruturados, eu consigo indicar para o Google(principal buscador) informações valiosas sobre meu site, inclusive a latitude e longitude que foi perguntada.

Esse [site](http://microdatagenerator.com/generator.html) gera o script de dados estruturados. Ele irá te entregar um script do tipo `application/ld+json` que você coloca no `head` da sua página. Segue exemplo que gerei nesse site:

```
<script type='application/ld+json'> 
{
  "@context": "http://www.schema.org",
  "@type": "Bakery",
  "name": "Minha Padaria",
  "url": "www.minhapadaria.com.br",
  "description": "Essa é a descrição da minha padaria",
  "address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "streetAddress": "Rua da Padaria, 29",
    "addressLocality": "São Paulo",
    "addressRegion": "SP",
    "postalCode": "00000-000",
    "addressCountry": "Brazil"
  },
  "geo": {
    "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
    "latitude": "38.844573",
    "longitude": "-77.286766"
  },
  "openingHours": "Mo, Tu, We, Th, Fr, Sa 06:30-20:00",
  "contactPoint": {
    "@type": "ContactPoint",
    "telephone": "+55(11)0000-0000"
  }
}
</script>
```

Há outros sites que geram isso, como:

http://microdatagenerator.com/generator.html

http://microdatagenerator.org/

Answer (score -1):

Pelo que pesquisei a tag existe, a questão é que não é um padrão oficial.

Na wikipédia explica um pouco sobre o padrão: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geotagging#HTML_pages

Por via das duvidas se o seu projeto for se beneficiar dessa informação é interessante utilizar mesmo que nem todos os buscadores o utilizem ainda, pois assim quando utilizarem seu projeto já estará funcionando com ela.